# JSON Objects with dynamic fields

Tags: c#, json.net

Imagine I have the following model:

```
public class A{
    public dynamic Data;
    public Error Error;
}
```

and I want to deserialize the following string:

```
"{
  "data": {
    "human": {
      "name": "Luke Skywalker",
      "height": 5.6430448
    }
  }
}"
```

How can I access `Data` like this?:
`var name=varOfA.Data.human.name` //string

Also I would like to cast `Data` like this:

`Person person=varOfA.Data.human as Person;
var name=person.name; //string`

Now, the Property Data is always a JObject, seems like this is not working https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/QueryJsonDynamic.htm

EDIT:
I probably have not explained myself well

I'm asking for after the Deserialization of a JSON of an A object, the Property Data of type dynamic is internaly an Annonimous Type (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/anonymous-types)
So I can access the type like `*.Data.human.otherInternalProperty.aPrimitiveField` or  `Person person=*.Data.human as Person` or `Person person=(Person) *.Data.human`

Comment: Can you try `var name = (varOfA.Data as dynamic).human.name`? I can't verify this by now, but I'm sure there is a way like this.

Comment: @vasily.sib I have updated the question

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try this?

```
dynamic dynData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a.Data); // a.Data is your json data
var data = dynData["data"];
var human = dynData["human"];
var name = dynData["name"].Value; // is name it what you're after?
```

EDIT: Made sample rextester -

> http://rextester.com/IDPHR38984

Code:

```
namespace Rextester
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            string json = @"{
                'data': {
                        'human': {
                            'name': 'Luke Skywalker',
                            'height': 5.6430448
                        }
                    }
                }
            ";

            A a = new A()
            {
                Data = json,
                Error = null
            };

            dynamic dyn = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(a.Data);
            var data = dyn["data"];
            var human = data["human"];
            var name = human["name"].Value;

            Console.WriteLine(name);
        }
    }

    public class A
    {
        public dynamic Data;
        public Error Error;
    }

    public class Error
    {
    }
}
```

Comment: I have updated the question. Your example is what I have now working, but I would like to avoid exposing the dynamic as a JObject. The idea is to use the same model in other serialization formats, etc...

Answer (score 0):

The following example demonstrates how to achieve what was requested in the question.

```
public static void Main() {

    string json = @"{
            'data': {
                    'human': {
                        'name': 'Luke Skywalker',
                        'height': 5.6430448
                    }
                }
            }
        ";
    dynamic varOfA = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json);
    string name = varOfA.data.human.name;
    Console.WriteLine(name); // Luke Skywalker      
    Person person = varOfA.data.human.ToObject<Person>();
    name = person.name; 
    Console.WriteLine(name); //Luke Skywalker
}

public class Person {
    public string name { get; set; }
    public double height { get; set; }
}
```

While the deserialized JSON will be converted to a `JObject` by default, by using a `dynamic` the desired value can be extracted directly.

Use `JObject.ToObject<T>()` to convert values to strongly typed objects as needed.

Comment: I have updated the question. But your answare seems to be the better for now